# Retrieving custom field value from Checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On the WooCommerce Checkout page, I have added an extra field the customer must enter to checkout.

I want to access this field's value in the woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees action hook.

I have tried several ways by using woocommerce->customer data and order data but cannot get the value. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
/* WooCommerce Add Extra Fees */
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','endo_handling_fee' );
function endo_handling_fee() {
 global $woocommerce, $post;

 if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
      return;

 // Get the order ID
 $order = new WC_Order($post->ID);
 // to escape # from order id 
 $order_id = trim(str_replace('#', '', $order->get_order_number()));

 // Here is where I want to get the field value
 $orderFee = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'decedents_name_field', true );

}
```

Comment: You have to show us *how you've added* the custom field.  Please show us that code, and we can tell you how to *get* that custom field.

Comment: When you are calculating the cart fees, the order hasn't been created yet so you can't expect to `get_post_meta()` from an order that doesn't exist.

Comment: Any update on this one? I'm looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem. I had a delivery fee that needed to be applied if fewer than a certain number of products were in the cart AND the user wanted a delivery (my custom field). What I ended up doing to solve this was sending the data to the server via AJAX like so:

```
jQuery("select#delivery_pickup_field").change(function(e) {
    var data = {
        action: 'woocommerce_delivery_fee',
        security: wc_checkout_params.apply_delivery_nonce,
        delivery_option: this.value 
    };

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
        data: data,
        success: function (code) {
            if (code === '0') {
                jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
            }
            console.log(code);
        },
        dataType: 'html'
    });
    return false;
});
```

Then take that data and put it in a SESSION variable

```
// Give server access to status of delivery select
add_action('wp_ajax_woocommerce_delivery_fee', 'ajax_add_delivery_fee', 10);
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_delivery_fee', 'ajax_add_delivery_fee', 10);
function ajax_add_delivery_fee() {
    if(isset($_POST['delivery_option'])) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['delivery_option'] = $_POST['delivery_option'];
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

From there, your server now has access to whatever value your custom field has.

```
// Adding delivery fee if fewer than 6 items is in cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'minimum_delivery_fee' );
function minimum_delivery_fee($instance) {
    global $woocommerce;
    @session_start();
    $order_meta = $_SESSION['delivery_option'];

    if(($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count < 6) && ($order_meta == 'delivery')) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __('Delivery Fee', 'woocommerce'), 15 );
    }
}
```

As helgatheviking pointed out, the order hasn't been submitted yet and doesn't exist. The only way I can see you getting the data you need is by sending it to the server via AJAX.

If this is confusing, check out the [source](http://phpwpinfo.com/how-to-update-shipping-cost-in-cart-dynamically-based-on-a-custom-field-in-woocommerce/) I used for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will use this in the future. However, I am not able to verify this works because I do not work on the site from my question at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution that don't require AJAX:
The field values are stored in:
WC()->checkout()->get_value('post_data')

In my case I had to add a fee of 2% of on payments (2nd payment and up);

I added a custom field to billing fileds, note use of class *update_totals_on_change* to trigger cart recalculation to add the fee.

```
function number_of_payments_select($fields ){
    //print_b($checkout);


    $cartTotal=WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();
    //echo $cartTotal;
    $paymentsArray=array();
        for ($i=1; $i<=12 ;$i++){
            $paymentsArray[strval($i)]= $i.' Payments(amount to pay: '.($cartTotal/$i+$cartTotal/$i*($i-1)*1.02).'currency)';
        }



    $fields ['billing_number_of_payments']= array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array('number_of_payments form-row-wide update_totals_on_change'),
        'label'         => 'Number of payments',
        'required'    => true,
        'options'     => $paymentsArray);

        return $fields;

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'number_of_payments_select', 10, 1 );
```

Then I get the number of payments selected by parsing (WC()->checkout()->get_value('post_data')

```
    function add_payments_fee(){
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        return;
    }


    parse_str (WC()->checkout()->get_value('post_data'),$post_data);
    $number_of_payments=$post_data['billing_number_of_payments'];
    if ($number_of_payments>1) {
        $cartTotal=WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();
        $payment_fee=$cartTotal/$number_of_payments*($number_of_payments-1)*0.02;
        WC()->cart->add_fee('fee', $payment_fee);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','add_payments_fee');
```